# preventDefault() on an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML and jQuery that slides a `div` up and down to show or hide` it when a link is clicked:

```html
<ul class="product-info">
  <li>
    <a href="#">YOU CLICK THIS TO SHOW/HIDE</a>
    <div class="toggle">
      <p>CONTENT TO SHOW/HIDE</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('div.toggle').hide();
$('ul.product-info li a').click(function(event){
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle(200);
}
```

My question is: How do I use `preventDefault()` to stop the link acting as a link and adding "#" to the end of my URL & jumping to the top of the page?

I can't figure out the right syntax, I just keep getting an error saying

> preventDefault() is not a function.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit weird to ask this question 14 years later, but: Why not use a button instead?

Comment: @Discostu36 in my case, the third party that supplies our html and css to skin wrote it as an <a> and changing it to a button breaks all the css.  Everytime they make an architecture decision, they make the wrong one.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$('div.toggle').hide();
$('ul.product-info li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Here is the page about that in the [jQuery documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/#preventdefault)

Answer (score 74):

Set the **`href`** attribute as `href="javascript:;"`

```
<ul class="product-info">
  <li>
   <a href="javascript:;">YOU CLICK THIS TO SHOW/HIDE</a>
  <div class="toggle">
    <p>CONTENT TO SHOW/HIDE</p>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice little gem for anchors --thanks! Could anyone describe why this works?

Comment: @KLVTZ `href` attribute of anchor tag (`a`) may not be empty... But we can set it to `javascript:<code-here>`, that is legal/valid. We then enter for `<code-here>` just an empty statement by adding a semicolon. This way the link does nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This allowed me to implement a back button functionality (remembering the state set by pushState() accross pages) into CalePHP's breadcrumbs like this $this->Html->addCrumb('Sessions', 'javascript:window.history.back();');

Comment: This is an old answer but was still bad advice even then. Use JavaScript to attach event handlers to elements, not HTML. And don't abuse HTML by using an anchor element with an `href` attribute (which should navigate the user somewhere else) to initiate behavior (something that buttons are meant for).

Answer (score 46):

1 - Easy way:

```
<a href="javascript:;">Click Me</a>
```

2 - using void(0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click Me</a>
```

3 - Using `preventDefault()`:

```
<a href='#' onclick="event.preventDefault()">Click Me</a>
```

4 - Yet another way of doing this in Javascript using `inline onclick`, `IIFE`, `event` and `preventDefault()`:

```
<a href='#' onclick="(function(e){e.preventDefault();})(event)">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Hi, or simply `<a href='#' onclick="event.preventDefault()">Click Me</a>`

Comment: @ankabot yup. I believe this is in some other answers though. I just wanted to add an answer with a different way not mentioned. Also to show different way of doing thing in Javascript. (there are unlimited ways to do things in JS!).  The top answers are easier to read and more practical. This is an just for theory not practice :)

Answer (score 45):

It's suggested that you do not use `return false`, as 3 things occur as a result:

1. event.preventDefault();
2. event.stopPropagation();
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

So in this type of situation, you should really only use `event.preventDefault();`

[Archive of article - **jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160603125641/http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you could just return false from the click event:

```
 $('div.toggle').hide();
 $('ul.product-info li a').click(function(event){
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle(200);
+ return false; 
 });
```

Which would stop the A-Href being triggered.

Note however, for usability reasons, in an ideal world that href should still go somewhere, for the people whom want to open link in new tab ;)

Comment: yeah, i think i was answering what i thought your intent was instead of the question :)

Comment: For what its worth, many years ago it was touted that you should return -1 to prevent the href from being triggered. I don't think that works in ANY browsers anymore, and you must "return false" to prevent the page jumping.

Answer (score 13):

This is a non-JQuery solution I just tested and it works.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
addEventListener("load",function(){
    var links= document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        links[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
        alert("NOPE!, I won't take you there haha");
        //prevent event action
        e.preventDefault();
        })
    }
}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
    <p id="p1">Paragraph</p>
</ul>
</div>
<p>By Jefrey Bulla</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<ul class="product-info">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">YOU CLICK THIS TO SHOW/HIDE</a>
      <div class="toggle">
        <p>CONTENT TO SHOW/HIDE</p>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Use

> javascript:void(0);

Comment: @AhmadSharif I have tested on FF 40.0.3 and IE 11 today, there are still work.

Comment: I think void(0) can be ugly/confusing to users, who can see it when they hover the link.  You can actually put any valid JS, so I like to put a comment that describes what it does. e.g. `href="javascript:// Send Email"`

Comment: This is an old answer but was still bad advice even then. Use JavaScript to attach event handlers to elements, not HTML. And don't abuse HTML by using an anchor element with an `href` attribute (which should navigate the user somewhere else) to initiate behavior (something that buttons are meant for).

Answer (score 6):

After several operations, when the page should finally go to `<a href"...">` link you can do the following:

```
jQuery("a").click(function(e){
    var self = jQuery(this);
    var href = self.attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    // needed operations

    window.location = href;
});
```

Comment: Why do `preventDefault`, and then do the default action yourself? Just do what you need to add, and let the default still take place.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just do it in css?

Take out the 'href' attribute in your anchor tag

```
<ul class="product-info">
  <li>
    <a>YOU CLICK THIS TO SHOW/HIDE</a>
    <div class="toggle">
      <p>CONTENT TO SHOW/HIDE</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your css,

```
  a{
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: This way will lose the :hover attribute in the bad browsers (ie family)

Answer (score 5):

If stopping the propagation of the event doesn't bother you, just use

```
return false;
```

at the end of your handler. In jQuery it prevents the default behaviour and it stop the event bubbling.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of `return false;` from the event call to stop the event propagation, it acts like an `event.preventDefault();` negating it. Or you can use `javascript:void(0)` in href attribute to evaluate the given expression and then return `undefined` to the element.

Returning the event when it's called:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;"> ... </a>
```

Void case:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"> ... </a>
```

You can see more about in: [What's the effect of adding void(0) for href and 'return false' on click event listener of anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048143/whats-the-effect-of-adding-void0-for-href-and-return-false-on-click-event-l/40048197#40048197)

Answer (score 1):

In **Javascript** you can use it

```
window.event.preventDefault();
```

It works in my case.  write the above line into your function.