# How to make an anchor tag refer to nothing?

Tags: jquery, html

I use jQuery, I need to make some anchor tags perform no action.

I usually write it like this:

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

However this refers to the top of the page!

Comment: because jquery will handle the click event so I want the link to be like an achor link but behave like a JavaScript function

Comment: effective dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers below: if you don't want a link to point to a resource, don't use the A element.

Comment: Don't use the `href` attribute at in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Href attribute for JavaScript links: “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/134845/1529630)

Comment: Dont add and 'href' attribute

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you don't want to have it point to anything, you probably shouldn't be using the `<a>` (anchor) tag.

If you want something to look like a link but not act like a link, it's best to use the appropriate element (such as `<span>`) and then style it using CSS:

```
<span class="fake-link" id="fake-link-1">Am I a link?</span>

.fake-link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Also, given that you tagged this question "jQuery", I am assuming that you want to attach a click event hander. If so, just do the same thing as above and then use something like the following JavaScript:

```
$('#fake-link-1').click(function() {
    /* put your code here */
});
```

Comment: This has a problem: it doesn't allow tab-navigation.

Comment: Note that (as Iraimbilanja points out) the span approach here disables the possibility to invoke the function using the keyboard, which I would consider a usability problem.

Comment: Also an accessibility problem. You can resolve it by using a button element (generated from JavaScript so non-JS users don't get a broken control).

Comment: If it's a button that doesn't have a plain HTML fallback (links to a page or an anchor), then making it tab-navigable doesn't really serve much purpose for screen readers (of course, I could be wrong because I'm not too up-to-date on screen readers' JS capabilities).

Comment: Here's a quick fix for that: tabindex="0" on a non-link element will enable keyboard navigation in most modern browsers.

Comment: @Tyson Screen readers read what is on the screen, if the browser supports JS, then so does the screen reader. Of course, the JS might display information in a way that doesn't draw the attention of the reader, or do something that depends on sight to use - but that is a different issue. Generating the button from JS avoids presenting a useless control to users without JS.

Comment: Another 'problem' is that you don't the CSS :hover pseudo class won't work on elements that aren't links in IE6. But since you're adding these elements through JavaScript anyway (at least, you should), you could just as well write a script that adds a .hover class to the element when hovered.

Comment: Yes, this person obviously has no idea what semantic markup is, or has ever worked with accessibility

Comment: This is bad because I need the anchor to look like a standard default link (which may be different on different browsers)

Answer (score 308):

There are a few less than perfect solutions:

**1. Link to a fake anchor**

```
<a href="#">
```

Problem: clicking the link jumps back to the top of the page

**2. Using a tag other than 'a'**

Use a span tag and use the jquery to handle the click

Problem: breaks keyboard navigation, have to manually change the hover cursor

**3. Link to a javascript void function**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<a href="javascript:;">
```

Problem: breaks when linking images in IE

**Solution**

Since these all have their problems, the solution I've settled on is to link to a fake anchor, and then return false from the onClick method:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">
```

Not the most concise of solutions, but it solves all the problems with the above methods.

Comment: I usually use the javascript:void(0); approach, because using # displays the current URL in Firefox's bar on mouse over, which can be misleading for the user.

Comment: `breaks when linking images in IE` What does this mean?

Comment: @eugene this question is 3 years old now, but IE used to make images disappear when surrounded by a link to a void function. Not sure when it was fixed, but it works in IE10, which is all I have installed. I personally now use `<a href="javascript:;">`

Comment: if you put "return false" in onclick then you can leave out the # anchor altogether.. the href is never used in this instance.. But make sure the empty href="" is still there, as some browsers need it..

Comment: I have used comments in there, too: <a href="javascript:void(0); // Show properties palette">. That way, when user hovers, they see the comment which can give them a hint what to expect when they click. (Although you could use a tooltip, too.)

Comment: This should be the best answer. Works perfectly in SPA with hash history.

Comment: It seems that `href="javascript:"` is also enough and works in the latest major browsers. No need for the semicolon, in fact PhpStorm even suggests to remove it.

Comment: For folks coming to this thread from the React world, best to not use href="javascript:" as react will stop supporting this soon. Getting this warning

Comment: Warning: A future version of React will block javascript: URLs as a security precaution. Use event handlers instead if you can. If you need to generate unsafe HTML try using dangerouslySetInnerHTML instead. React was passed "javascript:;"

Answer (score 50):

To make it do nothing at all, use this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> ... </a>
```

Comment: or just `<a href="javascript:;">`.

P.S. doesn't work with `target=_blank` though

Answer (score 39):

The correct way to handle this is to "break" the link with jQuery when you handle the link

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="theLink">My Link</a>
```

JS

```
$('#theLink').click(function(ev){
    // do whatever you want here

    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Those final two calls stop the browser interpreting the click.

Comment: While that does sound like it's "proper" because it stops event bubbling, "return false" is a lot less verbose and does the same thing. The only time you would want to do that is if you already have event handlers registered to clicks on links via jQuery.

Answer (score 34):

There are so many ways to do it like

Dont add and `href` attribute

```
<a name="here"> Test <a>
```

You can add onclick event instead of href like

```
<a name="here" onclick="YourFunction()"> Test <a>
```

Or you can add void function like this which would be the best way

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"> 
<a href="javascript:;">
```

Comment: Is the name attribute required?

Comment: @PetrusTheron Not necessary . .

Comment: This is a rip-off of pre-existing answers

Comment: Don't forget to set the style of your anchor tag if you remove the `href` attribute as it will no longer behave like a hyperlink (even though the onclick still works) you'll have to reset stuff like `cursor: pointer;` and the `:hover` selector.

Comment: @Partack Correct.. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 24):

What do you mean by nothing?

```
<a href='about:blank'>blank page</a>
```

or

```
<a href='whatever' onclick='return false;'>won't navigate</a>
```

Comment: Agreed - just return false from your jQuery method and voila, it won't go anywhere

Answer (score 17):

This answer should be updated to reflect new web standards (HTML5).

This:

```
<a tabindex="0">This represents a placeholder hyperlink</a>
```

... is valid HTML5. The tabindex attribute makes it keyboard focusable like normal hyperlinks. You might as well use the `span` element for this as mentioned previously, but I find using the `a` element more elegant.

See: https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html
and: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href

Some JavaScript to respond to clicking the link (or tabbing to the link, pressing Enter):

```html
<script type="module">
    let linkActivated = e => {
        alert(`Event triggered: ${e.type}`);
    };

    document.querySelectorAll('a:not([href])').forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
            if (e.key == 'Enter') {
                linkActivated(e);
            }
        });

        el.addEventListener('click', linkActivated);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is also valid HTML4, but it won't style the anchor as a link.

Comment: I didn't know it was valid html4, but the HTML5 spec explicitly mentions the use-case. And styles which don't target the href attribute will work just fine, just the default browser styles may be an issue.

Comment: This also doesn't trigger `click` event when user focuses the element and presses enter (tested in Firefox 51).

Comment: @torvin, that's simple. Use the `keydown` event.

Comment: snazzy quirk, but in window 10 it adds a bordered box around the element

Comment: @KaraRawson what do you mean "in window 10"? What browser and version? Link to a jsfiddle or similar reproduction case? As mentioned before, default browser styles *might* be an issue, but usually a reset CSS can help with that, or simply overriding the offending rule.

Comment: this was in an electron 1.76 application using Chromium. The front end was using react and semantic-ui. You were right about the default style.. it can be overridden with `outline:0;`';

Answer (score 15):

I think you can try

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0)">link</a>
```

The only catch I see over here is high level browser security may prompt on executing javascript.

Though this is one of the easier way than

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link</a>
```

this should be used sparingly

Read this article for some pointers https://web.archive.org/web/20090301044015/http://blog.reindel.com/2006/08/11/a-hrefjavascriptvoid0-avoid-the-void

Comment: Correct answer, allows tab navigation.

Answer (score 13):

Here are the three ways for `<a>` tag's `href` tag property refer to nothing:

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0)"> link </a>

<a href="javascript:;">link</a >

<a href="#" onclick="return false;"> Link </a>
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of [the currently highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925252/1000608), but with less info

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd add my two cents anyway:

It depends on what the link is going to do, but usually, I would be pointing the link at a url that could possibly be displaying/doing the same thing, for example, if you're making a little about box pop up:

```
<a id="about" href="/about">About</a>
```

Then with jQuery

```
$('#about').click(function(e) {
    $('#aboutbox').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This way, *very* old browsers (or browsers with JavaScript disabled) can still navigate to a separate about page, but more importantly, Google will also pick this up and crawl the contents of the about page.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that worked for me was a combination of the above:

First the `li` in the `ul`

```
<li><a onclick="LoadTab2_1()" href="JavaScript:void(0)">All Assigned</a></li>
```

Then in the LoadTab2_1 I manually switched the tab divs.

```
$("#tabs-2-1").hide();
    $("#tabs-2-2").show();
```

This is because the disconnection of the  also disconnects the action in the tabs.

You also need to manually do the tab styling when the primary tab changes things.

```
$("#secTab1").addClass("ui-tabs-active").addClass("ui-state-active").addClass("ui-state-hover").addClass("ui-state-focus");
    $("#secTab1 a").css("color", "#ffffff");
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure all your links that you want to stop have `href="#!"` (or anything you want, really), and then use this:

```
jq('body').on('click.stop_link', 'a[href="#!"]',
function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can have an HTML anchor (`a` tag) without an `href` attribute. Leave off the `href` attribute & it won't link to anything:

```
<a>link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! It perfectly worked for my case. Where I wanted to have Anchor tag to open in new tab when there is URL, but nothing if no URL. In case of # it was accepting a CLICK and moving it to top of the page. Having no href part as you suggested. It solved the issue! Formatting looks great due to a tag, click issue gone with no href. Thank you!!!

Comment: If anyone else is thinking if it is HTML5 valid, then answer is YES :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/33046203/5323892  . Here is from example from standards page (see the 3rd li item) :  <nav>
 <ul>
  <li> <a href="/">Home</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="/news">News</a> </li>
  <li> <a>Examples</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="/legal">Legal</a> </li>
 </ul>
</nav>

Comment: It works but if you want the mouse pointer to change to finger, just add href="JavaScript:void(0)" as suggested on @Rutesh Makhijani 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by

```
<a style='cursor:pointer' >Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="SomeFunction()"  class="SomeClass">sth.</a>
```

this was my anchor tag. so return false on onClick="" event is not usefull here.
I just removed href="#" property and it worked for me just like below

```
<a onclick="SomeFunction()"  class="SomeClass">sth.</a>
```

and i needed to add this css.

```
.SomeClass
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: What do u mean with that. What is recommended and why?

Comment: Its good practice to keep javascript and html in separate files, here's a detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue on a WordPress site. The headers on dropdown menus always had the attribute `href=""` and the header plugin being used only allowed standard urls. The easiest solution there was just to run this code in the footer:

```
jQuery('[href=""]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will prevent blank anchors from doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

React no longer support using a function like this `href="javascript:void(0)"` in your anchor tag, but here is something that works pretty well.

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => null} >link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop redirect to another page after clicking on the link you can do the following

```html
<a href="/your-page" onClick={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}>link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is tagged as a jQuery question, but you can answer this with AngularJS, also.

in your element, add the ng-click directive and use the $event variable which is the click event... prevent its default behavior:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">
```

You can even pass the $event variable into a function:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething($event)">
```

in that function, you do whatever you want with the click event.

Answer (score -4):

In HTML5 just remove the `href` attribute

```
<a>Your text</a>
```

Comment: Same answer as this one from 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771598/2227743