# How to select multiple elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to JQuery/Javascript etc... based on the following article: 
[How to make an anchor tag refer to nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924790/how-to-make-the-a-href-tag-refer-to-nothing)

I would like to apply the java function to several id's. Can we not make the function execute for classes as opposed to ids?

```
<span class="style1" id="myid">Link</span> 
<span class="style1" id="myid">Link</span>
<span class="style1" id="myid">Link</span>
<span class="style1" id="myid">Link</span>
<span class="style1" id="myid">Link</span>

$('myid').click(function() { 
    /* put your code here */ 
});
```

Basically as above, how do I execute the function above for ALL of the links? Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what link? All I see in your markup is `<span>` ...

Comment: `id`s must be unique within a document, you cannot have elements with the same `id`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I am now using classes instead. When I said "link" - I was referring to the span class, (as reference from the other article)...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following

```
$('.style1').click(function() {      
    /* put your code here */  
});
```

This adds a click handler to all elements with class containing `style1`. You should not have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 32):

you should name the IDs uniquely,

```
<span class="style1" id="myid1">Link</span> 
<span class="style1" id="myid2">Link</span>
<span class="style1" id="myid3">Link</span>
<span class="style1" id="myid4">Link</span>
<span class="style1" id="myid5">Link</span>
```

then use this code

```
$('#myid1,#myid2,#myid3,#myid4,#myid5').click(function() { 
    /* put your code here */ 
});
```

Comment: I suggest `$(".style1").click(function () {//whatever});`

Comment: +1 this answers the original question, but in this case one single class selector would have done the job.

Comment: this is what i needed because i have different radio buttons i needed to behave this way. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First off, IDs should  be unique.  You should not have multiple elements with the same ID.

To select by ID in jQuery use the `#` character.  `$('#myid')`.  This will get the first element with that ID, as there should only be one (you can kinda cheat by doing `$('[id="myid"]')` to get get multiple elements with the same ID).

I suggest using a class to select all of your links.  Classes are selected using the `.` character.

```
$('.style1').click(function(){});
```