# Is it valid HTML to have an anchor tag without href and without name?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is it valid HTML to have an anchor tag without href and without name? In our app we have some delete links which are disabled (hence no `href` attribute), but still shown to the user.

---

<sub>I am posting this question on behalf of [Joshua Muheim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1439143/joshua-muheim) which was asked in the [comments of a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510353/497418). It is very similar to the original question, but different enough that I felt it was worthwhile to open it as a separate question.</sub>

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I thought it was self-evident that the original question was about whether it was ok to have an `<a>` element without an `[href]` attribute while this is more specifically about whether it's ok to have an `<a>` element without an `[href]` attribute **and** without a `[name]` attribute. That said, I don't mind if this gets closed. I just figured it was worth turning into something searchable in case other people had the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valid to use <a> (anchor tag) without href attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510191/valid-to-use-a-anchor-tag-without-href-attribute)

Comment: This may be a slightly different question than the original, but the answer you give here was already provided there, word for word. IMO this provides even less information for anyone with either of the problems than the original

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it's valid, [the HTML spec says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-a-element):

> If the `a` element has no `href` attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents.

Comment: This doesn't answer the `name` part, which is the only aspect of the question which is unique from the other posts about anchors and `href`.