# Using anchor tags for onepage scrolling or in tabs are not good for SEO, how can I create a bootstrap tab without "href="#"?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have read that using anchor tags for onepage scrolling or in tabs are not good for SEO. How can I create a bootstrap tab without `href="#"` and I found that donw in this [website](http://www.asmhijas.com/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510191/valid-to-use-a-anchor-tag-without-href-attribute         same question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had gone through the website you attached http://www.asmhijas.com/ and i found that he did replaced href="#id" with data-target="#id" you can read more about it here ":- http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp