# <a> tag inside <label> tag not triggering checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to use `<a>` inside a `<label>` tag. Because there are many css styles only apply to `<a>` in our current system. The `<a>` tag is not linking to any pages but for styling/hovering.

See code below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
<label for="my-id"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Some text</a></label>
```

But when clicking on "Some text", it doesn't toggle the checkbox status.

I've tried `$.preventDefault()`on the `<a>` tag but doesn't work.

What should i do to make the `<a>` behaves like a label?

Comment: In the a tag add `onclick="c(this);"`
create a new function
`function c(obj){
$(obj).parent().prev().prop('checked', true);
}`

Comment: you likely want `<input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
<label for="my-id" style="cursor:pointer">Some Text</label>`

Comment: @DavidThomas The [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) does allow an `<a>` inside a `<label>`.

Comment: Any reason for having the `href` attribute in your `a` element? If you remove it, clicking on the text will toggle the checkbox.

Comment: An `<a>` tag is allowed in a label in case of anchoring or actual linking only. If you want it to LOOK like a link, apply the same styles to the label or a `<span>` inside the label. Don't bastardize a link for appearance.

Comment: @John: I stand corrected! (And slightly appalled, but definitely corrected) Thanks!

Comment: @GOTO0 Wow! It really works! Just saved my ass!

Comment: Why are you using an `<a>` tag, if you are not using it for a link?

Comment: @RyanHu Happy to help :D

Comment: @RyanHu Be aware that when you remove the _href_ it invalidates the element

Comment: @LGSon thank you for your reminder :)

Comment: @LGSon The `href` attribute is not required on `a` elements. Previous versions of the spec contained an ambiguous formulation, but this [was made clear](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href) in the current draft.

Comment: @GOTO0 Thank you very much ... have missed that completely ... that is a good answer, please post it and you'll have my upvote

Comment: @LGSon One more answer...? :P [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42038354/1083663).

Comment: @GOTO0 One more is always welcomed if it is good and not already given :) ... upvoted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the `href` attribute from the `a` element, clicking on the text will toggle the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
<label for="my-id"><a>Some text</a></label>
```

As the HTML spec [states](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href):

> The `href` attribute on `a` and `area` elements is not required

Comment: @BladeMight In fact, the hyperlink is not required in this case.

Comment: Oh that how it is... I was thinking that <a> purpose is hyperlink, am I wrong?

Comment: @BladeMight Not at all, but it can also be used as a placeholder [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10510353/1083663), [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19167175/1083663).

Answer (score 3):

*Updated: this answer were given before the edit where made, which now invalidated it, still, I'll leave it for the ones it can be useful*

---

Give the `a` anchor `pointer-events: none`

```css
label[for="my-id"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label[for="my-id"] a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
<label for="my-id"><a href="#">Some text</a></label>
```

If you need to support older browser, use a pseudo element to cover it

```css
label[for="my-id"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
label[for="my-id"]::after {
  content:  ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
<label for="my-id"><a href="#">Some text</a></label>
```

Comment: This has very limited browser support.

Comment: @Soviut The global support is about 93.58%, you find that limited?

Comment: On many browsers, especially mobile browsers, it's only just started being supported. Chrome 53 on Android was the first version. Any older versions will still treat it as a link. Besides, the OP wants the style of a link, not an actual href.

Comment: @Soviut I added an option for all those ... down to IE8 if the single colon is used on the pseudo class ... and the OP said: _I have to use <a> inside a <label> tag._

Comment: @LGSon thank you very much. But it also kills onhover behavior which I need for styling in this case. I missed that in original question, already edited.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `<a>` only for styling. Use a class on the label instead.

```css
.my-link-style {
  /* To match the cursor style for an <a> */
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /* Add more styles here */
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id" />
<label for="my-id" class="my-link-style">Some text</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the anchor element on the outside of the label element.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><label for="my-id">Some text</label></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
<label for="my-id"><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="my-id">Some text</a></label>
<script>
  document.querySelector("label[for=my-id] > a")
  .onclick = function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById(
      this.parentElement.htmlFor
    );
    el.checked = !el.checked;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse, include label in a:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my-id" >
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><label for="my-id">Some text</label></a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tanz79u2/1/)

Comment: Main question was: `when clicking on "Some text", it doesn't toggle the checkbox status.` I think my example solves it, who and why downwoted?