# HTML a tag without href attribute, what happens when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am tying to understand a project where used JQUERY to manipulate the DOM.
I have the following element:

```
<a data-modal-trigger data-modal-target=".modal-confirm" class='confirm-modal-trigger' style='width: 1px;'></a>
```

In the javascript code  I have this tag clicked by the code:

```
$(".confirm-modal-trigger").click();
```

But there is no call-back function definiton attached to this event like:

```
$(".confirm-modal-trigger").click(function(){....});
```

or 
    $(".confirm-modal-trigger").on("click", function(){....});

I am searching trough the whole project files and nothing. Then what is the purpose of clicking this `a` tag if there is no `href` attribute nor there is a call back function defined when button is clicked?

And the most strange part is that when I comment this line

```
$(".confirm-modal-trigger").click();
```

The code doenst work as it should.

*** EDIT ***

I read the proposed original answer, and I still don't uderstand why when commented the `.click()` the pop-up window that normally appears (when not commented) doesen't appear when I comment this line. If there is no action behind it - just a sematnic meaning, why I observe that behaviour?

Comment: Probably the click event is bound somewhere else (i.e. `$('.confirm-modal-trigger').on('click', function() {  });` or similar).

Comment: ParthRaval Link says 404 on my machine.

Comment: @ParthRaval that link is dead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid to use <a> (anchor tag) without href attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510191/valid-to-use-a-anchor-tag-without-href-attribute)

Comment: .click() is use to trigger the "click" event ... .click(function () {}) is use to define a function that will be called when a "click" event occurred on the selected jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess (without seeing the codebase) but: most probably the event is delegated to a parent or ancestor element, which could make it quite hard to find in the code.

Say the element `.confirm-modal-trigger` has a parent, a `div` with ID "foo". The event may well be bound like so:

```
$('#foo').on('click', '*', function() {});
```

or

```
$('#foo').on('click', '> *', function() {});
```

or

```
$('#foo').on('click', 'a', function() {});
```

...the list of possibilities is potentially endless.

Comment: There is no parrent from wich to inherit the callback. I checked it.