# Page scrolls to the topmost part when opening a modal or window that assigns "overflow:hidden" to body

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, overflow

I've read over 10 threads/questions here but none of them works. I recently figured out how to show a modal that hides and/or disable the scrolling. Next, I figured out how to prevent my page from briefly shifting to the right for a second because of the removal of scrollbar (ugly effect). I ended up with the scrollbar still shown but disabled scrolling similar to Facebook when you open a modal there.

But, I'm facing a problem where it scrolls to the topmost part of the page automatically. I've tried a lot of things to address but to no avail.

1. Of course, I disabled the default click event by **e.preventDefault()**
2. I assigned overflow:hidden to body when opening the modal. I also did it with overflow-y:hidden to the body.
3. Some say when body is set to 100%, you set it to auto when you open the modal. It doesn't work. I did it vice versa, too.

I wanted to repeat that the codes below do work. They disable the scroll and not shift my page to the right because the scrollbar stays but just disabled. I wish to get rid of the abrupt scrolling to the topmost part of the page whenever I open the modal.

**UPDATE: I ADDED SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(".parentbox").show();
$("body").addClass("no-scroll");
});
```

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.no-scroll {
overflow: hidden;
}

.parentbox
{
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.box
{
position: absolute;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 28px 18px;
text-align: center;
width: 320px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<div class="content">
<p><strong>Top section</strong></p>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="parentbox">
<div class="box">
This is a modal
</div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a href="#">Open Modal</a>
<br/><br/><br/>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code so we can replicate the issue?

Comment: sadly im not in the place right now to give the snippet. I'll do it once I'm able

Comment: I added a snippet.

Comment: fyi, i tried to remove the modal altogether and it scrolls to the top. I think the problem has something to do with the overflow hidden entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove `href="#"` to prevent the page being scrolled to the top.

Edit: Although using a button is probably better.

> You should be using a button in this case. It's more appropriate from
>   both semantic and accessibility standpoints. Anchors should take you
>   somewhere, not perform an action.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510191/valid-to-use-a-anchor-tag-without-href-attribute#comment101272146_38478548)

Comment: I tried this but still doesn't work. I think the preventDefault() has addressed this.

Comment: I added snippet.

Comment: Use `position: fixed` save `window.scrollY` and restore it when the modal is closed.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/prevent-page-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-open/) explains how. It makes sense that `overflow-y: hidden` scrolls back to the top, you're clipping the content.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses. I fixed this by removing the height:100% on the html and body. I went back to where the scrollbar is getting removed causing the whole page to move to the right side. To fix the movement, I added padding:17px to the content div / body when is opened via Jquery.

Thanks!