# A tag with no link and onclick listener and appropriate hand icon

Tags: html

I'm using a template that includes an image that is link that when clicked takes the dashboard view to its home.

The HTML code is written like this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>CompanyName</span></a>
```

I need to do a simple modification. When this is clicked, instead of its current action it should open up a dialog and show some text. I will do this with a JS function. So I've modified the HTML so that it looks like this:

```
<a onclick="showDialog()" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>CompanyName</span></a>
```

This works just fine, but when the mouse hovers over the image the mouse icon changes to I instead of the hand.

To fix this, I tried modifying the HTML so like so:

```
<a href = "" onclick="showDialog()" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>CompanyName</span></a>
```

This works makes the mouse change into a hand, but clicking it reloads the page.

So my question is, how can I get the behaviour of the second option, but in such a way that the mouse, when hovering, changes to a hand and not to a I?

Comment: But look at the answers to [Valid to use <a> (anchor tag) without href attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10510191/215552)

Comment: Thank you fhthe suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't linking somewhere: **don't use a link**.

Use a `<button>` instead.

Apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

The `cursor` property determines what the mouse pointer will look like:

```
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: @PaulBaiju — `button` is a **type** selector, not a class selector. You will note that I recommended replacing the link with a button on the second line of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if I change to a button I change how the dashboard looks and the I don't want tomodify site_title because I did not write any of the CSS for this.