# Obfuscation link - Should i use span ou link a with href?

Tags: hyperlink, seo, obfuscation

I have a question about links obfuscation.

I want to do links obfuscation to prevent passing link juice to specific pages for SEO purpose. And also prevent search engine to go on unimportant pages... but i want to allow users to access to these pages.

Because Google says that even if a link has rel="nofollow", there are possibilities that he will follow the link even with nofollow directive.

I found some script that replaces the  < a href...> tags by a span tag.... but other scripts, only remove the href in the "a" tag.

So my initial question was : Is it recommended to use an "<a...>" tag without href attribute ?

I realize that it's faster to only remove the "href" attribute in "a" tag.. Because all CSS will be OK for the "a" tag (even without the href attribute).. and if i use span tag... i will need to edit my CSS file..
So that is why i used a tag without href...
Because i have multiple different style for links...

But in fact, my question should have been: Will my SEO affect negatively using "a" tag without href attributes ? And will search engine will see the "a" tag(without href) as a normal link.. and try to follow it and result as an error.. because no href attribute?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Pascal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valid to use <a> (anchor tag) without href attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510191/valid-to-use-a-anchor-tag-without-href-attribute)

Comment: Yes ! But my question was more about... SEO ! Using an < a > tag instead of a < span > tag will affect negatively my SEO ? or not ? Because i do link obfuscation for my crawl budget! Do search engine will see a "a" tag a a link.... even if no href ?

Comment: `<a>` without href is like a `<h1>` without content -> not useful. I think there is other detections, specially about angular clic, but it will mainly ignore unrelevant content, so if people can't interact with it -> it's not useful.

Comment: Also, [edit] your question to precise what you are looking for. Explain why your question is different from the one that I gave with example or stats or something

Comment: Hi :) i updated my questions :)

Comment: Presumably you are adding the `href` back into the `<a>` tag with JavaScript so that the links work for users?