# How to get div ID JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the ID or class if the link button is clicked

```
<div class="pane alt" id="a">
<h3>Nick says:</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada
<p><a href="#" class="btn-delete">Delete</a>  <a href="#" class="btn-unapprove">Unapprove</a>  <a href="#" class="btn-approve" style="display:none">Approve</a>
```

the code that i created to process the clicked button is this which resulting "undefined"

```
$('.btn-unapprove').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id); 

});
```

so is it possible to get the div id if the link is clicked ? if so how to to do it?

Comment: Use this instead: `var id = $(this).closest('.pane').attr('id');`

Comment: i tried to use .closest() but it seems it wont work when i try it on the browser the alert wont pop (not even undefined) and other functions seems not running. can someone help please.

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr` for such a live property for performance purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all: You should correct you HTML. Because if your HTML is not loaded correctly in DOM than the Jquery/Javascript also not provide correct result.**

In your HTML you are missing some closing tags like - "`</p>, </div>`"

```
<div class="pane alt" id="a">
  <h3>Nick says:</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="btn-delete">Delete</a>  <a href="#" class="btn-unapprove">Unapprove</a> 
    <a href="#" class="btn-approve" style="display:none">Approve</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

There are several ways to do accomplish this task.

You Can use Jquery **[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```
$('.btn-unapprove').click(function(){    
    alert($(this).closest('div.pane.alt').attr('id'));
});
```

[Wokring Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kt2yf/1/)

You Can use Jquery **[`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)**

```
$('.btn-unapprove').click(function(){    
    alert($(this).parents('.pane.alt').attr('id'));
});
```

[Wokring Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kt2yf/3/)

You Can use Jquery **[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**

```
$('.btn-unapprove').click(function(){    
    alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kt2yf/4/)

Comment: thank you very much dear sir, i dont know why closest() wont work for me but parents() worked like charm. cheers

Comment: @Apollo Belvedere: Your Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

```
This will help you to work done. Before doing this please correct your code and improve like following. In your code you didn't close the <p> tags.

I suggest don't use anchor tags there go with **fake-link** using <span>..
```

Refer : [How to make an anchor tag refer to nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924790/how-to-make-the-a-href-tag-refer-to-nothing)

```
<div class="pane alt" id="a">
<h3>Nick says:</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada</p>
<p>
<a href="#" class="btn-delete">Delete</a>
<a href="#" class="btn-unapprove">Unapprove</a> 
</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.btn-unapprove').click(function(){
        alert( jQuery(this).closest('div').attr('id') );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***`.closest()`*** in jquery

```
$('.btn-unapprove').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest('div.pane').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no ids on the buttons elements. If you set it your code will start working.

To get id of container use the code

```
var id = $(this).closest('.pane').attr('id');
```

inside the 'click' function.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/J53Ku/)

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
 $('.btn-unapprove').click(function(){

        var id = $(this).closest('.pane.alt').attr('id');
        alert(id); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).parents('.pane').attr('id');
```

Comment: how can you pass this id to php (code igniter)