# Get the id value from html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the html div below:

var htm_div = slider.target;

console.log(html_div); //Returns  the html div

```
<div id="layerslider_2" class="ls-wp-container fitvidsignore ls-v6 ls-container ls-responsive ls-device-is-desktop" style="width: 343px; height: 193px; margin: 0px auto; position: relative; visibility: visible;" data-layerslider-uid="LSzclf85rp7" data-current-slide="4">
  <div>....</div>
  <div>....</div>
  <div>....</div>
</div>
```

Using javascript or jQuery, I want to get the **id value** of this **div**. How to achieve this and thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `slider.target.id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get div ID JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677952/how-to-get-div-id-jquery)

Comment: @Taplar thanks it works with slider.target.id :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get an element's id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html_div.id` will give you access to the value of the `id` attribute using vanilla javascript.