# How can I create link that does nothing?

Tags: html

I want to create a link that does NOTHING, it means that its a fake link

Im trying with onclick="mijava();return false;" but it scrolls up in the website

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to create a link that does nothing? This sounds like an XY problem: you have one problem, and you think that creating an `a` element that does nothing will solve it. So... what is the issue you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("nothing").addEventListener("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault()
});
```

html:

```
<a id="nothing" href="#">Link</a>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogynL6d/)

Answer (score 3):

`"javascript:void(0)"` to `href` attribute, the `<a>` tag will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This won't do anything.

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

Comment: I believe it was not valid to write it like this, i just checked it and it is Valid! +1

Comment: But it will still scroll up to the top of the page, unless you `preventDefault()` it

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to style it like a link and you probably don't want to use an anchor tag if it's not going to act like one.

See this answer: [How to make an anchor tag refer to nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924790/how-to-make-the-a-href-tag-refer-to-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Do you test it that?

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```