# can I use document.getElementById(someid).onclick for tag a

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a javascript function onclick. I have written something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readPage(){
        alert("Hello");
    }

    document.getElementById('read').onclick=readPage;
</script>

<a id="read" href="">read</a>
```

I am trying to call readPage function but its not working?if I write onclick inside  tag it works but the way I have written above is not working. why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing wrong about how you do it, but when. You can not access the DOM `(like running getElementById())` before it has loaded. The easiest thing to do is to run you code inside `window.onload` like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById("read").onclick=readPage;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It will work with an empty `href` attribute (then the current URL of the page will be used),
but you have to use, as already mentioned,  `window.onload` to attach the click handler, or you have to move the `script` block **after** the `a` element.

Otherwise `getElementById` cannot find the element because it does not yet exist in the DOM tree.

```
<a id="read" href="">read</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function readPage(){
        alert("Hello");
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('read').onclick=readPage;
</script>
```

​
As already mentioned, you use e.g. `return false;` to make the browser **not** follow the URL. You even need this if you change the URL to `href="#"` because otherwise the browser will scroll the page to the top.

Test it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Nj4Dh/1/

---

Read more about the [traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html).

Answer (score 0):

You would first have to disable anchor's default direction protocol (i.e., not let a go to href)

1. Make `href="#"` on anchor.
2. Check the `event.preventDefault()` function example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag).

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readPage(){
        alert("Hello");
    }

    document.getElementById('read').onclick=readPage;
</script>

<a id="read" href="#">read</a>
```

Comment: nope its not working, I have written javascript function in some other .js file.

Comment: @Vipul: Make sure that you include that file in your current page using `<script src="path"></script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it really (Without any browser specific functions). One is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function stopDefault(e) //cross browser function for stopping default actionw
    {
        if (e && e.preventDefault)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            window.event.returnValue = true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function readPage(event){
        alert("Hello");

         return stopDefault(event);//prevent default action
    }



    window.onload = function(event){

         document.getElementById('read').onclick=readPage;


    }
</script>

<a id="read" href="#">read</a>
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stopDefault(e)
    {
        if (e && e.preventDefault)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            window.event.returnValue = true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function readPage(event){
        alert("Hello");

         return stopDefault(event);//prevent default action
    }

</script>
<a id="read" href="#" onclick="readPage(event)">read</a>
```

I've used the stopDefault function sd You need to stop the default action of a link, otherwise it will try to go to the url thats in the href.

Comment: @Felix Kling Oops I pasted that bit into the wrong place, thanks. Updated.

Comment: Oh ok :) Deleted my comment ;)