# Prevent a link to reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a responsive menu: [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/alxkI)

To avoid the page to be reloaded when I click a link I have:

```
$('nav.menu a[href="#"]').click(function () {
  $(this).preventDefault();
});
```

But this does not seem to work. When I click a button the menu disappears.

Does anyone knows what I am be doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [preventDefault() on an <a> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag)

Comment: See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag/10478514#10478514

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's not the element that need a `.preventDefault()`, its the click `event`.

**Try this:**

```
$('nav.menu a').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // or use return false;
});
```

I don't recommend to use the `href` as selector though, better to give it an `id` or `name`.

> *From MDN, about .preventDefault():*
>   Cancels the **event** if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event.

You can read more here:

- **MDN: [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)**
- **jQuery: [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

---

### There is a CSS way, using [**pointer-events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

So by using in the CSS `pointer-events: none;` all click will be ignored. This is a "recent" alternative and suported in IE11+, Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 2.0+, Safari 4+.

### [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WMwH/)

Comment: This is the solution actually.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but, in my example, it does not work. And I would like to use it only in the links with href=#" which are the ones that have a child menu ... Try to check my CodePen example ...

Comment: @Shapper, just checked the console on your pen. It is not loading jQuery, that is why. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/A8apu

Answer (score 7):

Here is very easy way to do it inside html.

```
<a class="font-weight-bold" href="javascript:void(0);"> Click Here </a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just return false.

```
$('nav.menu a[href="#"]').click(function () {
  return false
});
```

Comment: I like return false too.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but, in my example, it does not work. Try to check my CodePen example ...

Comment: @Shapper I have never used codepen, but it looks like the jquery library has not been included. You need to link to it in the code. "$ is not defined" is being returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use like that:

```
$('nav.menu a[href="#"]').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but, in my example, it does not work. Try to check my CodePen example ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.menu a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // stop the normal href from reloading the page.
});
```

Working codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cynEg

You did not have a reference to the jquery library included. Also the 'enquire' function is now throwing an error but preventDefault is working.

**Edit** I have commented out the second function.

Comment: Don't just link to codepen, if your link ever breaks your answer is useless.

Comment: @MatthewHinea sorry, I wrote that when I was a real newb. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('nav.menu a[href="#"]').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And an inline option without jQuery:

```
<a href="javascript:function f(e){e.preventDefault();}">Link</a>
```

And don't forget that with this you have already used the "f" name for a function, so don't name other function like this.