# an unwanted page refresh when executing simple query code

Tags: jquery, page-refresh

I want to learn jQuery but I can't figure out why my page keeps refreshing right after the on-click event is done.

The goal with this code is to change the background of DivResult. This works for a split seconds before the page is refreshed. I tried it on different browsers and different computers so i think it's something with my code.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click',function(){
        var kleur = "#" +$('#text').val();
        $('#DivResult').css({'background-color': kleur});
    });
});
```

and this is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jQuery_JavaScript_Library_v1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text">
        <button id="button">button</button>
    </form>
    <div id="DivResult">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: this is the 1000000th duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18575623/1845408, still people post answer quickly just to get reputation points.

Comment: That question is regarding the click of an `a` element, not the submission of a `form` as in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the default value for the type attribute of button elements is "submit".

source : [Can I make a <button> not submit a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form)

Solution :

```html
   <form>
        <input type="text" id="text">
        <button type="button" id="button">button</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `button` click is submitting the `form` which makes the page appear to refresh. To solve this issue you should hook to the `submit` event of the form and use `preventDefault()` to stop the form submission. Try this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var kleur = "#" + $('#text').val();
    $('#DivResult').css({ 'background-color': kleur });
});
```