# style.display = 'none' click event on modal jumps up to top of page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a modal that displays on a click event on my page. I've added an event listener to the 'close' link element in the top right of the modal, code as follows:

```
document.querySelector('.modal__close').addEventListener('click', () => {
            modal.style.display = 'none'
        })
```

This does indeed close/remove the modal, however, it also causes the page to 'jump' back up to the top (I've noticed it also adds a '#' to the end of the url), which is not the behaviour I want, how would I get the modal to just gracefully disappear and leave the underlying display exactly the same?

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `.modal__close` element please?

Comment: Try this html attribute value solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271220/7109092

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably that element is a link, so you should prevent its default action (which is to follow the link defined in the `href` attribute)

```
document.querySelector('.modal__close').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
      modal.style.display = 'none';
      ev.preventDefault();
})
```

As a side note, you might use instead a `<button>` element, that could be more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: That was it, thank you! Should have thought of that, shouldn't I.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have something like this :

```html
<a href="" class="modal__close"></a>
```

By default, if the link (*a*) doesn't have a **href** defined, it reload the current page (and add a #).

To skip it, you can do it by preventing the default action in your Javascript with an *event* parameter :

```js
document.querySelector('.modal__close').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
     ev.preventDefault();
     modal.style.display = 'none';
});
```

and in jQuery it would be easier :

```js
$('.modal__close').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(modal).css('display', 'none'); // can also be $(modal).hide();
});
```