# any idea instead of this <a>Like</a>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I write a simple script with php and mysql for rating of products on my website when I click on Like link it send product id through ajax and get total number of likes of products. But when I click on Like link page redirect to page.php but I want that my index page not redirect to page.php but product id send to page.php. I use this simple html tag.
Please help to resolving this issue.

```
<a href="page.php?id=ABC">Like</a>
<div class="likediv"></div>
```

AJAX/JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var catValue = "ABC";
  $.ajax({
   type:"post",
   url:"ajax_likedproduct.php",
   data:"catValue="+catValue,
   success: function(data){
     $('.likediv').text(data);
   }
  });
});
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['catValue'])) {
   $data = $_POST['catValue'];
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(likes) AS TotalLike FROM likes WHERE     product_id='".$data."';");
while($likes = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    if($likes['TotalLike'] == 0 || $likes['TotalLike'] == ""){
      echo'0';
    }else{
        echo $likes['TotalLike'];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your code where you use ajax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [preventDefault() on an <a> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag)

Comment: He's not using ajax. In fact, I think he doesn't even know how to. Please refer to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) for more information.

Comment: @TIMINeutron — He says he is using ajax: "when I click on Like link it send product id through ajax"

Comment: @Quentin: True, yet he's complaining of the <a> tag redirecting to the php page, which is exactly what he has on the href attribute of the tag.

Comment: @TIMINeutron — Which suggests the problem is likely the missing preventdefault … but the question is missing too much information to be sure enough to give an authoritative answer.

Comment: @Quentin: Look, I'm far from trying to be rude. But why would he even consider having the **exact same thing** he wants in the href? You simply do `href=#` and then make the call in ajax via onClick or binding it through js. It's highly unlikely (yet possible, as you have stated) that he knows what he's doing. That's why I pointed him to a basic tutorial so he can make an educated question, if needed.

Comment: @TIMINeutron — Because, having the URL in the href means that if the JS fails, then the link works, and you can have a generic function that reads the URL from the href attribute. That is Good JavaScript 101. See [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: You're sending the Ajax request as soon as the page is loaded, not when the link is clicked. You should solve that and also use [preventdefault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the full link you want in the original anchor `href` and decorate the desired links with a common class (for easier access):

```
<a href="ajax_likedproduct.php?id=ABC" class="like">Like</a>
<div class="likediv"></div>
```

and code like this:

```
// Use a single delegated handler for all like links
$(document).on('click', 'a.like', function(e){
   // Stop the normal click behavior
   e. preventDefault();
   // Use the existing URL for progressive enhancement
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
        $('.likediv').text(data);
      }
   });
});
```