# How to stop navigation in chrome browser soon after click action using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to stop the browser from loading soon after the click action;  is there any work-around for it.. or is there any JS implementation for the same..

Comment: maybe to use prevent default on any click on a tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag

Comment: I tried this 
@driver.execute_script("return $('.xyzlocators').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });")

Comment: no luck; anything i have to make changes in it?

Comment: one idea(paste this in console to try it): window.addEventListener("click",function(e){ console.log(e.target, e.path); event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); })

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript **setTimeout** and **setInterval** for delaying your click action.

```
 <a onclick="delayLoder()">Click</a>

  function delayLoder(){
        setTimeout(function(){      
            window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
        }, 3000);
     }
```

Comment: Actually I am navigating from one page to another page using a link; have to avoid navigation after click action. here is what i do
self.firstProperty.click

Comment: window.location is the location that we are currently at ? or the destination ?

Comment: @PrashanthSams it is destination.

If you want to stop navigation you can use event.preventDefault()
Using about code in answer your page changes after 3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, workaround I can think of, is to navigate to a '*wrong page*' straight  after the click. (i.e. http://www.notAvalidHTTPaddress.com). But if this is not fit for purpose, you can alternatively try to use the equivalent for sendkeys in JavaScript in order to hit **'ESC'** --> which in Chrome for example will halt page loading.

*In Java:*

```
public Keys soloKey(int key) throws AWTException  
{
      Robot r;
        try 
        {
             r = new Robot();
             r.keyPress(key);
             r.keyRelease(key); 
        }
            catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
}

soloKey(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

*In Javascript:*

```
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


keyboardEvent[initMethod](
                   "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                    true, // bubbles
                    true, // cancelable
                    window, // viewArg: should be window
                    false, // ctrlKeyArg
                    false, // altKeyArg
                    false, // shiftKeyArg
                    false, // metaKeyArg
                    27, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                    0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

The javaScript answer was taken from here:
[js-press-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programatically/596580#596580)

and here are the keyCodes (27 is ESC)
[js-key-codes](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm)

Hope this helps!