# Load dynamic data on <a href="url_of_data"> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently loading my page data dynamically clicking on an element like this:

`<a onclick="load('url_of_data')">Some Text</a>`

But for a better UX I now want to have an element like this:

`<a href="url_of_data">Some Text&</a>`

and then just use preventDefault like this;

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    var href = self.attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    load(href);         
});
```

I got this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag) question.

But it does not work, the site is still reloading and not running the function.

---

I now apply the click handler everytime the dynamic content was loaded and it works fine.

Comment: Where is the code for `load()`? What errors are thrown? Give a proper explanation of what should happen....broken code is not a good substitute for an explanation

Comment: When the `a` tag itself was dynamically loaded, you either have to reapply the click handler or you have to use jquery's `on` function overload with the additional selector argument.

Comment: Okay you are right, I now also added the click() event in the load() function and it works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to reapply the click handler everytime the dynamic content was loaded.

Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the container div to which the content will be loaded into.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    var href = self.attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    //Replace "self" with the container you want to load the content into, e.g. $("#myDiv").load(href);
    self.load(href);         
});
```

Comment: You chose the anchor as the container div it needs to load into?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan this is just an example. I have no idea whats the context and what he is planning to do with it. He can choose whatever he wants.

Comment: True, but maybe you can point it also out in the code (with a comment maybe), so your code is more clear.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan i did :)

Comment: The load function is not the problem, the problem seems to be that preventDefault isn't preventing the page reload

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return false` at the end of your function

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   var self = $(this);
   var href = self.attr('href');
   e.preventDefault();

   load(href);
   return false;         
});
```

Comment: This will say that load is not defined.

Comment: how you defining your `load` function

Comment: You need to gibe the load function a container where the content will be loaded into. (self.load(href)) or it won`t work. Have you tested your code? it returns an error.

Comment: You don't need `return false` when `preventDefault()` is already used

Comment: load() is defined just above the $('a').click();

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will make the work.

```
$('a').click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');

    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   var self = $(this);
   var href = self.attr('href');

  window.location.assign(href);
});
```

It helps you

Comment: This answer makes no sense