# Ajax goes to url instead of changing data Django

Tags: django

I'm using ajax in Django to activate add to favorites button, here are my files

**urls**

```
path('<int:pk>/favorite_item/', views.favorite_item, name='favorite_item'),
```

**views.py**
@login_required

```
def favorite_item (request, pk):
    favitem = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    data = {
        'is_fav': Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, item=favitem).exists(),
    }

    if data ['is_fav']:
        Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, item=favitem).delete()
    else:
        new_entry = Favorite.objects.create(item=favitem, user=request.user)

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

finally **HTML**
only the part of the script

```
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
    $("#add_to_fav").click(function () {
      console.log( $(this).val() );
    });
              $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("data-favorite_item-url"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.results').html(data);
        },

      });


  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Now when I click the element that should trigger the whole action, the function is already working and the item is removed or added to db, but it takes me to another page which only has 1 sentence (`{"is_fav": true}`) or (`{"is_fav": false}`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preventDefault() on an <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `preventDefault` to stop your browser from actually going to the linked page when the link is clicked. You need to change lines 3 and 4 of the code you included like this:

```
    {% block javascript %}
  <script>
    $("#add_to_fav").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log( $(this).val() );
    });
              $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("data-favorite_item-url"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.results').html(data);
        },

      });


  </script>
{% endblock %}
```