# smooth scrolling to a div container after clicking an anchor link in the navbar (centering the div container in the middle of the viewport/screen)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

Excuse the long and maybe confusing title.

What I am trying to achieve is that when I click a link in my navbar-dropdownmenu the (new loading) page will automatically scroll smooth to the corresponding container centering it in the middle of the screen.

For now I use the *scroll-behavior: smooth* feature in CSS, but that always aligns the container with the top of the screen, which is really not a great experience for the user.

I tried about 20 different JS Codes from older posts with a close to similar problem so far, but nothing worked out :(

This is my Website, since the scrolling doesnt work in CodePen:
https://gisbertstestsite.xyz/dist/htmls/leistungen.html

[image: those are the links in the dropdownmenu, they are corresponding with the divs on the page]
Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="snap-wrapper">
        <div id="main1" class="snap-box box_1">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active dropdown"><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html"><i
                                class="fas fa-cut"></i> Leistungen</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-class">
                            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Herren">Herren</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Damen">Damen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Jugend_Kinder">Jugend und Kinder</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Farben_Strähnen">Farben und Strähnen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Wellen_Glätten">Wellen und Glätten</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#EPT">Extension | Perücken | Toupets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Kuren">Kuren</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Brautservice">Brautservice</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Kosmetik">Kosmetik</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/covid.html"><i class="fas fa-hands-wash"></i> Covid-19</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/inspiration.html"><i class="fas fa-images"></i> Inspiration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/jobs.html"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> Jobs</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><span><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Mehr</span>
                        <div id="more_dropdown" class="dropdown-class">
                            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/mehr htmls/impressum.html"> Impressum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/mehr htmls/datenschutz.html"> Datenschutz</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main class="content">
                <div class="preisliste">
                    <div class="blurwrapper katalog">
                        <div class="Katalogbeschreibung">
                            <h2>Leistungskatalog</h2><br>
                            <span>Hier finden Sie einen Auszug aus unserer akutellen Preisliste. Alle Preise richten
                                sich
                                nach
                                dem Arbeitsaufwand und können ggf. abweichen und sind eingeteilt in kurzes bis langes
                                Haar.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="blurwrapper Herren" id="Herren">
                        <div class="table">
                            <table class="fl-table">
                                <caption>Herren</caption>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Leistung</th>
                                        <th>Länge</th>
                                        <th>Preis</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Kurzes Haar</td>
                                        <td>30€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Mittellanges Haar</td>
                                        <td>35€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Langes Haar</td>
                                        <td>40€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="blurwrapper Damen" id="Damen">
                        <div class="table">
                            <table class="fl-table">
                                <caption>Damen</caption>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Leistung</th>
                                        <th>Länge</th>
                                        <th>Preis</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Kurzes Haar</td>
                                        <td>30€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Mittellanges Haar</td>
                                        <td>35€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Langes Haar</td>
                                        <td>40€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="blurwrapper Jugend_Kinder" id="Jugend_Kinder">
                        <div class="table">
                            <table class="fl-table">
                                <caption>Jugend und Kinder</caption>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Leistung</th>
                                        <th>Länge</th>
                                        <th>Preis</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Kurzes Haar</td>
                                        <td>30€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Mittellanges Haar</td>
                                        <td>35€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Langes Haar</td>
                                        <td>40€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="blurwrapper Farben_Strähnen" id="Farben_Strähnen">
                        <div class="table">
                            <table class="fl-table">
                                <caption>Farben und Strähnen</caption>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Leistung</th>
                                        <th>Länge</th>
                                        <th>Preis</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Kurzes Haar</td>
                                        <td>30€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Mittellanges Haar</td>
                                        <td>35€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Langes Haar</td>
                                        <td>40€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="blurwrapper Wellen_Glätten" id="Wellen_Glätten">
                        <div class="table">
                            <table class="fl-table">
                                <caption>Wellen und Glätten</caption>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Leistung</th>
                                        <th>Länge</th>
                                        <th>Preis</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Kurzes Haar</td>
                                        <td>30€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Mittellanges Haar</td>
                                        <td>35€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Waschen und Schneiden</td>
                                        <td>Langes Haar</td>
                                        <td>40€</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <br>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here the CSS:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html,
body {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
html {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* For Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* For Internet Explorer and Edge */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* For Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

.snap-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-image: url(/images/chester-wade-0AlE0lFaKF8-unsplash.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff1a4f;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .active {
  background-color: #ff573a;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.13rem;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li span,
.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li a {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 2.3rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ff8c00;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .dropdown-class {
  display: none;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown-class {
  width: 40rem;
  display: list-item;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff8c00;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li:hover #more_dropdown {
  width: auto;
  display: list-item;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff8c00;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown-class ul {
  display: block;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown-class ul li {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem ridge #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown-class ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown-class ul li:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10rem 25rem 0 25rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content .preisliste {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: inherit;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content .preisliste .blurwrapper {
  scroll-margin-top: 200rem;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 2.6s ease-in-out;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content .preisliste .blurwrapper::after {
  content: "";
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content .preisliste .blurwrapper * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content .preisliste .Katalogbeschreibung {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 70px;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content .preisliste .Katalogbeschreibung h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box .content .preisliste .table {
  min-width: 60%;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem 35rem 7rem;
}

.fl-table {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5);
}

.fl-table caption {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.fl-table td,
.fl-table th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.fl-table td {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.5);
}

.fl-table thead th {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #4fc3a1;
}

.fl-table thead th:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #324960;
}

.fl-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.5);
}

/* Responsive */
```

Comment: You have to prevent the default behavior on clicking a link. `e.preventDefault()` -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/265499/5781499 and handle the scrolling via js: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: it seems that you have smooth scrolling in the web page what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I will tryout marcs hint ^^ thx!
What I want is that it scrolls down but centering the element in the middle of the screen if possible.. with css it always scroll the element to the top of the screen ^^

Comment: @Gisbert12843 then try "scrolTo" instead of "scrollIntoView" Good luck with the calculations ;) Can be helpfull: https://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/scroll.html