# Access custom URL on link click (userscript)

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

Im looking for a way to open an edited URL when I click on a certain link on a certain page, using userscript.

But I want to be discreet, so without

- editing the the DOM (not changing the href url)
- sending any request to the original url

Im not quite sure if `@run-at document-start` is fast enough to detect and redirect url before accessing the original url. I feel not.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? is it even possible?

Comment: 1. If your script is running at `document-start` (thus as fast as possible), then it may run before the anchor element exists. 2. Add a `click` event listener and use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Since im not entirely sure how fast `document-star` is, `event.preventDefault()` seems better and its also exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preventDefault() on an <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag)